# inverse of the modulus in $L^p$

Tags: lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces

We all know that, given any bounded open set $\Omega\subset \mathbb R$
$$\frac{1}{x}\in L^p(\Omega)\iff p<1 \qquad \frac{1}{x}\in L^p(\Omega^c)\iff p>1$$

what do these conditions become for a dimension greater than $1?$

Is there a formula to say if
$$\frac{1}{|x|}\in L^p(\Omega)$$
for $\Omega\in \mathbb R^n$ in the two cases $0\in \Omega$ and $\Omega$ unbounded?

Comment: The only issues are at $0$ and $\infty$, so try spherical coordinates.

Comment: For $\Omega$ a neighborhood of $0$, you can use spherical coordinates to address the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $\Omega$ a neighborhood of $0$, say $\Omega=B(0;1)$ in $\mathbb{R}^d$ one has

$$
\int_{B(0;1)}\frac{1}{\|x\|^p}\,dx =\sigma_n\int^1_0\frac{r^{n-1}}{r^p}\,dr=\sigma_n \int^1_0\frac{1}{r^{p-n-1}}\,dr
$$

Similarly
$$
\int_{B(0;1)^c}\frac{1}{\|x\|^p}\,dx =\sigma_n \int^\infty_1\frac{1}{r^{p-n-1}}\,dr
$$

where $\sigma_n$ is the surphace area of the $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$ sphere.
From here you can draw conclusions.